# I need a video player [or an addon for WMP/MPCHC/VLC] that has 'Smart Playlists' (a la iTunes)?

Tags: windows, windows-media-player, vlc-media-player, media-player, media-player-classic

> iTunes [..] Smart Playlists based on powerful features like My Rating, Last Played, Keywords, and Total Play Count.

Basically I watch a bunch of old reruns of TV shows on shuffle in a playlist.

I'd like to be able to tag the episodes with keywords (relating to the plot or whatever), and also give them subjective star ratings.

- I want to be able to press a button and search the tags, to skip to a file in the playlist.
- I want to be able to have the player play highest rated (stars), least recently watched (history), etc.

Lots of music players exist with these features.. I am having a lot of trouble finding a video player with these features.

I need it to work on Windows.

edit 1: WMP has "auto playlists". As soon as you click create auto playlist, it hardcodes in a condition for your music library. No consideration given to video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as keywords and star ratings go, Windows Explorer is absolutely magnificent in this capacity.

From the Videos library, you can add tags by selecting your video files, right clicking and choosing `Properties`, and going into the `Details` tab (works for most video formats, save maybe for .flv).
[image: Properties Window]

Then you can search for them using the searchbox and the `tag:` operator for Windows' search.
[image: Search using the tag: operator]

Some other search operators you might need:

- `accessed:` You can choose dates and date ranges for this, like "this month" or "past 3 years".
- `rating:`

For most of them, you just type in the operator and it'll give you a dropdown with possibilities.

When you get the list, you can just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the videos and drag them into WMP, VLC, whatever. You can also hit the <kbd>Save Search</kbd> button on the Windows Explorer toolbar to put it into that strange little Search folder in your profile folder.